# eventListener callback function for keydown triggered twice

Tags: reactjs, next.js, addeventlistener, keydown, js-scrollintoview

I have a menu at the right side and related description at the left and I want to change selected item in the menu when I press arrowDown or arrowUp keys.
but every time I press the key the callback function triggered twice and scroll two by two not one by one!! I do't know whats wrong with my code.

I defined an event listener in `componentDidMount` like this:

```
public componentDidMount () {
 global?.window && global?.document.addEventListener('keydown', e => this.handleKeyPress(e));
}
```

and the callBack:

```
private handleKeyPress = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
    const {activeType} = this.state;
    const {allSolutions} = this.props;

    const index = allSolutions.findIndex(x => x === activeType);
    if (event.key === 'ArrowDown') {
      this.scrollToSolutions(allSolutions[index + 1]);
    } else if (event.key === 'ArrowUp') {
      this.scrollToSolutions(allSolutions[index - 1]);
    }
  }
```

scrollToSolution:

```
private scrollToSolutions = (id?: number) => {
    const item = document.getElementById(id?.toString() ? id.toString() : '');
    this.setState({activeType: id});
    if (item) {
      item.scrollIntoView({block: 'center'});
    }
}
```

thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that componentDidMount is not being called more than once, as this would add multiple event listeners.
you have a typo in the lifecycle method name (***componenDidMount*** should be ***componentDidMount***). If the name is incorrect, the method won't be called as a lifecycle method, and if it's called manually somewhere else in your code, it could lead to multiple event listeners.

Comment: I had a mistake when I was writing the question. I don't have any typo in my code. just edited my question.thank you

Comment: i added a console.warn in `componentDidMount` and it shows the message twice...

Comment: ok, then you should investigate where is this happening and fix that.
also, take into consideration as a good practice to
Unbinding Event Listeners: In **componentWillUnmount**, make sure to unbind the event listener using **removeEventListener** to avoid memory leaks and potential duplicate bindings in case the component is mounted again.

Comment: I also added `removeEventListener` but still have the issue

Comment: @FatemeM you mentioned that you got the log twice from the component.
are you working with the strict mode in React?
where you are rendering the component did investigate what is causing the 2 times rendering?
are you using context API or state management tools like Redux?

Comment: yes I am using strict mode... I unset it and now it works properly.. so it is only in development mode ... thank you so much for your help.